# How to implement login session in asp.net and C#

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and C# and I want to ask how to implement a session login using asp.net and C#.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

In C# you can define a session variable like this:

```
Session["userame"]= txtusername.Text;
```

where txtusername is a text box. In another page you can call it as:

```
string usrname = Session["username"].ToString();
```

To check whether a user is logged in or not, in a particular page; you'll have to check  if this session is empty or not. If the session is null then redirect the user to login page else he/she can view the page. Same logic applies to all the pages where you want to implement the session validation. Sample (on Page_Load event):

```
if (Session["username"] == null)
   Response.Redirect ("Login.aspx");
```

Hope it helps... :)

Comment: Is there a better way than checking "Username"? I feel like if there was some other bug (Such as allowing null usernames) then its not reliable... Some kind of flag? Either here, on in the cookie itself?

Comment: @Worthy7 you can use asp.net's internal profile feature. Follow this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Comment: In the end I entirely ditched sessions and moved to encrypted tokens.

Comment: @Worthy7 Well... You did ask for session implementation in the question and hence the answer...

Comment: **asked 8 years ago, not by me**

Comment: @Worthy7 Ahh I See... Question is asked another user.

Comment: @domlao I hope it had helped earlier. Please mark as answer if it was satisfactory answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

The question is broad answer, in Simply you can follow like this

- Create database, user table in sql server or any database of your choice
- Create the login form with userid and password
- Check them with database for user availability
- If User exist and password matches create a session, like Session.Add ("Userid", txtUserid.Text);
- In other pages (restricted pages where only registered users allowed) write this code in every page load event

  if (Session["Userid"] == null)
      Response.Redirect ("Login.aspx");

Answer (score 3):

```
Session["login_user"] = "[username]";
string username = Session["login_user"].ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to implement session is as following:

```
Session["SessionName"] = Value;
```

For retrieving value

```
String variable = Session["SessionName"].ToString();
```

Note: Session variable can be of any type.

Generally session is used for checking whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: This questions is over 9 years old and your answer adds nothing new to it